# How to generate a preview with a .binding as variable type?

Tags: swiftui

```
struct View1: View {
  enum Field {
    case username, password
  }

  @State var passwordText: String = ""
  @FocusState var focusedField: Field?

  var body: some View {
    View2(text: $passwordText, placeholder: "Password", focused: $focusedField)
  }
}

struct View2: View {
  @Binding var text: String
  let placeholder: String
  var focused: FocusState<View1.Field?>.Binding     // << here !!

  var body: some View {
    HStack {
        TextField(placeholder, text: $text)
            .frame(minHeight: 44)
            .padding(.leading, 8)
            .focused(focused, equals: .password)     // << here !!
        if text.count > 0 {
            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                .padding(.trailing, 8)
        }

    }
  }
}
```

In View2, I can't find a way to be able to generate a preview view. What should I pass into focusedField?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This compiles, although whether it actually works…?

```
struct View2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static let focusedState = FocusState<View1.Field?>()

    static var previews: some View {
        View2(text: .constant("text"), placeholder: "placeholder", focused: focusedState.projectedValue)
    }
}
```

Do you actually *need* the FocussedState in `View2`? Perhaps you'd be better off to move that back up to `View1`

```
View2(text: $passwordText, placeholder: "Password")
    .focused($focusedField, equals: .password)
```